# iReport is searching for java.exe file in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, exe, ireport

I have a *iReport-5.6.0* file downloaded and after configuring the *ireport.conf* file as:

```
jdkhome="\usr\lib\jvm\java-7-openjdk-amd64"
```

When I try to run the *iReport*, it's showing as java.exe file not found in the above location. I am trying to run it in Ubuntu.

Comment: .exe files are for windows. In linux the executable is just called `java`.

Comment: [Download the the `tar.gz` file extension one and install it, that should work for ubuntu](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer/releases)

Comment: i tried the same, its again asking for java.exe file

Comment: Then it's an issue with iReport and not much to do with programming. I would suggest asking their support team for help.

Comment: Change the jdk home to point to the bun directory : jdkhome="\usr\lib\jvm\java-7-openjdk-amd64\bin"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following below steps worked for me.

1. There is a ireport file inside bin folder of the iReport package.
2. Give it read-write permissions for all user groups.
3. Open your terminal and go to the bin folder.
4. Then type "./ireport".